# Difficulty in plotting particle trajectories in Schwarzschild spacetime

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make 3d plots of particle trajectories in Schwarzschild spacetime by solving geodesic equation, using NDSolve in Mathematica. Although I am getting solution as interpolating functions, plot is not showing anything.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica stack.exchange. A couple of comments: 1. Not everyone here knows what the geodesic equation is, let alone what the resulting expression is for the case of a Schwarzschild spacetime. 2. In general, we prefer that people show their efforts in Mathematica and post some code, so we can easily copy-paste in our notebooks and try to help out. So perhaps, keeping these in mind you would like to edit your post :-)

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include a **minimal working example**; i.e., include enough Mathematica code (not a picture) that replicates your problem. You can copy from your input cell and use the `{ }` icon in the Edit window for formatting code.